# Anyone knows of open source flash games

Tags: flash, open-source

I am thinking of developing a small flash game. I was considering my different alternatives. One of them obviously involves working with some open source projects. Does any of you know of an open source flash game? Something similar to a shootup'. Is it even realistic to expect such a thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any open source flash games you can contribute to but you should consider one using the *fantastic* API [**flixel**](http://flixel.org/) made by Adam Atomic so you will learn how to use it.

Comment: You can find a tutorial series at http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/12/02/creating-a-flash-platform-game-with-flixel-and-flex.aspx that will show you how to get started with Flixel.

Comment: As an update 10 years later, this [repo](https://github.com/AdamAtomic/flixel/) hasn't been maintained since 2011. And it's already 2019 when I was writing this, so yeah...Flash is pretty dead.

Answer (score 2):

If you do some googling you can find some basic Flash games like Asteroids with tutorials and source code available.

Generally speaking, you aren't going to find a lot of serious API's or engines for games floating around for Flash since Flash programming tends to be rather gridlocked in with visual design.

On the flip side, something like Alterniva3D could arguably be called a gaming engine since it has basic precepts of gravity and keyboard movement built right into it... but 3D programming in Flash is quite an advanced topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use Flixel (and you really should), there are a number of games with the source code available for your perusal.

- [Asteroids clone](http://github.com/AdamAtomic/FlxTeroids)
- [Space Invaders clone](http://github.com/AdamAtomic/Mode)
- [Side-scrolling platformer/shooter](http://github.com/AdamAtomic/Flx-Invaders)
- [Pong clone](http://flixel.org/forums/index.php?topic=456.0)
- ["Edgecrement"](http://flixel.org/edgecrement.zip) and ["I Love You 2"](http://flixel.org/ilu2_src.zip) (I don't know much about these)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try Madness Interactive, it's open source with plenty of stuff. Might be a big game but plenty of things to learn from there, and much simpler than you think, just dissect the easy parts of it. It's a shooter, really awesome.